# How to update a column for all rows in a database in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, database, yii

Suppose I have a table named "table1"

### table1

cl1 || cl2 || cl3

with columns "cl1", "cl2" and "cl3". How can I update all the rows  for the column "cl3" in the database without giving any condition.

Comment: Asking a question requires for you to have done some basic knowledge / research..

Comment: well what is the field name of that column?

Comment: My model name is "Absence" model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use query `UPDATE table1 SET cl3='value'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `updateAll(array $attributes, mixed $condition='', array $params=array ( ))` method.

Check [THIS](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#updateAll-detail) link.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a condition then you simply don't supply one:

```
UPDATE table1
SET cl3 = "something"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
UPDATE `table1` SET `cl3`='value'
```